# Networked AR Unity can't make a bullet a child of the ground plane stage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I am trying to make an AR game and am currently using Unity's high-level networking classes. I have set my player prefab to be spawned in one of the two network spawn locations, which are both childs of the Ground Plane Stage. When user has tapped to make their ground plane stage and has tapped to be the host, their player character appears. Unfortunately, if they press the fire button, the bullets appear above the stage and unscaled, meaning they aren't parented to the stage. This confuses me because I've checked many times and the bullet emitter is a child of the player, and in my code it references said emitter. Thus I'm rather confused why the bullets don't seem parented.

I've attempted to attach a script to make the bullet emitter a child of the player when it spawns. I've also tried making it a child of the stage when it spawns. I've tried making the player character not dependent on the Network manager spawning it when the player joins, but then that leads to other networking problems when it comes to controlling the character, but it can shoot then.

The only one that was relatively successful was making the bullet a child of the stage when it spawned, but it would only stay in one place. Attempting to make the bullet a child of the player did nothing

```
  //This is the class I'm trying to use to make the object a child of 
    something
    public class AddToBeetle : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            GameObject player = 
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
            transform.SetParent(beetle.transform, false);
        }
    }
```

It rarely prints any error messages. I hope that I can eventually get the bullet to spawn in front of the player model when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Oh gosh I was dumb, the one thing I didn't apply the script to was the player's bullet emitter. It was super late and that's probably why I missed trying it on that. Anyway I hope this helps someone else if they ever have to deal with AR and Unity.